# Swift, Firebase Cloud Function - INVALID ARGUMENT error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call a cloud function from firebase by using the following code.

Client code -

```
func checkUserStatus() {
    let functions = Functions.functions(region: "us-central1")
    
    let argument  = [
        "currentUser":
            [
                "email": "test@email.com",
                "uid": "LP8R4yZroyMTj"
            ]
    ]
    
    functions.httpsCallable("subscriptionStatus").call(argument) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("FAILED")
            print(error)
        } else {
            print("PASSED")
           print(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Cloud Function code -

```
exports.subscriptionStatus = functions.https.onRequest(async (request: Request<RequestBody>, response) => {

    const {
        currentUser,
    } = request.body

 // Logic goes here

 }
```

But getting the following error when running it

> Error Domain=com.firebase.functions Code=3 "INVALID ARGUMENT" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=INVALID ARGUMENT}

The function takes in a parameter called *currentUser* which further comprises of *user's email and uid*.
Any lead would be highly appreciated on the matter.

Comment: I think the issue is your dictionary. Try passing in just '["email": "test@email.com","uid": "LP8R4yZroyMTj"]' and see if the error is persistent.

Comment: Just tried that and getting the same error message.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue. Your cloud function is an 'onRequest'. It needs to be a callable function if you're going to use it like that. You can find more information at these docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function

Comment: Oh, is there a way to call a function of type *onRequest* from the client-side?

Comment: I believe you have to invoke the function by calling the http url: `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/subscriptionStatus`

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to have an answer to the question for anyone else having a similar issue.

To call an `onRequest()` cloud function you need to use the URL where it's deployed at i.e. `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/<function-name>?<var-name>=<var-value>`

If you're wanting to call it in the client app using `call`, then you'll need to use an `onCall()` cloud function.

Firebase has a one of the best documentation on their services: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

OnCall functions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

onRequest functions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: I just followed the documentation and was able to get back the result via a https call.